# Not able to call cosmos stored procedure from power automate flow

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, power-automate

I have a stored procedure in my cosmos db collection with will either create and update document in cosmos db collection based on session Id. If any document with session id is present in then update else create the document and it works fine when I call in locally from cosmos db.Below is the sp script.

But I am trying top execute it from power automate flow using the **Execute Stored Procedure V2** connector but I am getting the following exception.

Sp Script:

```
function UpsertItemInCollection(item) {
    
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    
    var parsedItem = JSON.parse(item);
    
    var queryToCheckExist = "SELECT * FROM testcontainer c where c.sessionId = " + "'" + parsedItem.sessionId + "'";
    
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        queryToCheckExist,
        
    function (err, dbItem, options) {
        
        if (err) throw err;

        if (dbItem.length < 1) {
            
            collection.createDocument(collection.getSelfLink(), parsedItem, options, handleCreateOrUpdate);
        }
        else {
            var itemToUpdate = dbItem[0];
            itemToUpdate.marketingData.eventLabel = parsedItem.userData.eventLabel;
            itemToUpdate.marketingData.eventName = parsedItem.userData.eventName;
            itemToUpdate.marketingData.source = parsedItem.userData.source;
            itemToUpdate.marketingData.country = parsedItem.userData.country;
            itemToUpdate.marketingData.postCode = parsedItem.userData.postCode;
            itemToUpdate.marketingData.createdAt = parsedItem.userData.createdAt;
            collection.replaceDocument(itemToUpdate._self, itemToUpdate, options, handleCreateOrUpdate);
            // getContext().getResponse().setBody(dbItem[0]);
        }
    });
    
    function handleCreateOrUpdate(err, item, options) {
        
        if (err) throw err;

        getContext().getResponse().setBody(item);
       
    }
    
    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('Something went wrong while stored procedure execution.');
}
```

Power Automate Flow:

[image: Flow Calling SP]

Exception:

[image: Exception]

Can anyone help me? I think I am not passing the param correctly.

Comment: I check the item param value by logging it is null i don't know why.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code and found there are some changes needed.
**Change for Power automate: -**
The input JSON you are passing through PowerAutomate must enclosed within square braces e.g., *[{"id":"1","name": "DemoData"}]*. Please [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/documentdb/#execute-stored-procedure-%28v2%29) .

**Change in Cosmos DB stored procedure :-**

1. Need to remove `var parsedItem = JSON.parse(item);` code from Cosmos DB stored procedure. As PowerAutomate's Execute-stored-procedure-(v2) accepts JSON as parameter for stored procedure.
2. Inside else condition you have used `userData` which is not declared/defined anywhere in the stored procedure. I have replaced it with `marketingData` and worked for me.

Below are reference screenshots.

[Input for Execute-stored-procedure-(v2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWH8F.png)

[Flow success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqvrg.png)

**Stored procedure code** (I tried updating a single field in sample data with the modified code)

```
function  UpsertItemInCollection(parsedItem) {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var queryToCheckExist = "SELECT * FROM c where c.id = " + "'" + parsedItem.id + "'";
var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
collection.getSelfLink(),
queryToCheckExist,
function (err, dbItem, options) {
if (err) throw err;
if (dbItem.length < 1) {
collection.createDocument(collection.getSelfLink(), parsedItem, options, handleCreateOrUpdate);
}
else{
var itemToUpdate = dbItem[0];
itemToUpdate.name = parsedItem.name;
itemToUpdate.marketingData.eventName = parsedItem.marketingData.eventName;
collection.replaceDocument(itemToUpdate._self, itemToUpdate, options, handleCreateOrUpdate);
// getContext().getResponse().setBody(dbItem[0]);
}
});
function handleCreateOrUpdate(err, item, options) {
if (err) throw err;
getContext().getResponse().setBody(item);
}
if (!isAccepted) throw  new  Error('Sone thing went wrong while sp execution.');
}
```

**Sample input json for power automate**

```
[{
"id": "706cd7c6-db8b-41f9-aea2-0e0c7e8eb009",
"name": "updatedName53",
"categoryId": "4",
"price": 45.99,
"tags": [
"tan",
"new",
"crisp"
],
"marketingData": {
"eventName": "eventName53"
}
}]
```

While running the stored procedure in Cosmos DB data explorer, you can pass the json as Custom parameter but without square braces.

[Input params of stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAoVu.png)

[Executed stored procedure successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63HlC.png)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

The issue has been resolved by passing the payload like [{"id":"1","name": "DemoData"}] 
 as you mentioned from power automate action.